# Azure Active Directory Verify Access Token in Web Api outside of Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, access-token

If my Web Api application is hosted outside Azure, can I use access tokens issued by Azure AD and verify the tokens in the Web Api itself or against Azure AD?
All the examples available are referring to the Web Api applications hosted on Azure. But there must be a way to do this with Web Api outside Azure.
Any reference to solution would help.

Comment: Take a look at [the official sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet/). The example can run locally, which means the API app runs outside of Azure, but still using Azure AD as protection. I think most of the samples can run outside of Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure active directory support the OAuth 2.0 to authorize the third-party apps. It doesn’t matter where the web API or apps hosted. Below figure is the stand OAuth flow from [RFC 6749 – The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-8).

[image]

Technically, the web API only need to verity the token from the endpoint it trust. I also explained the detail about verifying the access token from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866513/how-to-validate-azure-ad-security-token/39870281#39870281).

And if you want to know more about the scenarios developing with Azure AD, you can also take a look this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/).