# How to use ConfigurationManager? (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols)

Tags: c#, configuration, openid-connect

I was recently forced to update my System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt NuGet package to 5.1.4 because of another NuGet package. 
Most of the code after changes seem easy enough to solve, but now `ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>()` takes two arguments instead of one!
I can not find any example of how to use this new version of the Configuration manager!

I use it as part of this code:

```
string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Format("{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", authority);

ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, IConfigurationRetriever<>);

OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
_issuer = config.Issuer;
_signingTokens = config.SigningTokens.ToList();

_stsMetadataRetrievalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Can anyone let me know what arguments `ConfigurationManager` expects

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found that in order to make `ConfigurationManager` work with version >=5.1.4 of the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` NuGet package you have to add `OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever()` as the second argument.

The correct invocation of `ConfigurationManager` is then:

```
ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
```

Comment: You can also use `AddJwtBearer(o => o.options.MetadataAddress = "")`

Comment: @cSteusloff Since this question is about instantiating `ConfigurationManager` I think you need a bit more context for your comment to make sense.

Comment: You can create the default implementation of `ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>` when you set the `MetadataAddress`. In your example you create only the default Manager.

Comment: Hi @Jeppe, do you know what is the difference between JwtBearerOptions.Authority and JwtBearerOptions.MetadataAddress. I set only JwtBearerOptions.Authority ="my-openid-connect" url and the token validation is working, and seems to discover the publick keys from the given address assigned to JwtBearerOptions.Authority.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you want to do, you could just change the code to make a call to the Configuration retriever, like this:

```
        string issuerEndpoint = "https://my.auth.server";
        var openidConfiguration = await OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(
                    $"{issuerEndpoint}/.well-known/openid-configuration", CancellationToken.None);

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            TokenValidationParameters =
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = openidConfiguration.Issuer,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    IssuerSigningKeys = openidConfiguration.SigningKeys,
                    IssuerSigningTokens = openidConfiguration.SigningTokens
                }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Diego, looks like a nice alternative if some of the helper classes do not work. Unfortunately it can not work for me as the code is in a method to just retrieve and verify the token, not for login.

Comment: Ahh, okay, just posted it here to make available to others, maybe you could find a similar solution to your problem.

Comment: Be aware that `OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync()` doesn't cache the retrieved configuration, while `ConfigurationManager<>.GetConfigurationAsync()` does so