# Validating token from Azure App Service through postman returns 401

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I've integrated my application with Azure AD authentication.
While I can successfully login through the same, I want to access the response claims sent by AD post re-direction of my application from AD to homepage.

So, I've followed [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to) to get the response claims.
i.e., **https://app-name.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me**

I can see access-token, id-token etc in my response, while I hit the url from my browser.

Now, for my API URLs to get validated, I've to pass access-token in my authorization header.
But, also, I want to validate the passed access token (from API) through Azure service, for which the way is:

```
POST https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"id_token":"<token>","access_token":"<token>"}
```

I want to test the same first through postman, but, I get **401 unauthorized**.

[image]

Comment: I assume you want to validate the tokens your webapi are receiving right? Take a look in the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870281/1384539

Comment: Try to add bearer token in Postman. Go to Authorization tab, from the _type_ drop down select _Bearer Token_ and provide the token.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I've gone through the link, seems like, it is not exactly the same which I need. I'm expecting the workaround as per the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to

Comment: @Michael tried that too, the same error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `aad` provider, just pass the `{"access_token":"<access_token>"}` in the body.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#validate-tokens-from-providers):

[image]

First, login to  `https://app-name.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`, copy the `id_token`(not the `access_token`).

[image]

Then in the postman, pass the `id_token` copied to the `{"access_token":"<access_token>"}`.

[image]

Comment: it worked! thank you. Its somewhat ambiguous in MS Docs. :)