# Jwt.io self populating the signature

Tags: jwt, jwt.io

I am very new to jwt and signature validation. I had a very basic query.
I am generating a token from MSAL(AAD).
When I use the token in jwt.io, I can see that it automatically populates the secret key and marks the signature as verified. How does jwt.io know about this?

[image: ss of jwt.io]

From generating token point of view, I didn't mention anywhere explicitly to generate the token with any secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the details of your token here (which is ok), but I assume the token has a `kid` and maybe also a `jku` in the header.

The `kid`is the [Key Id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4), and the `jku` the [JSON Web Key Set URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.2).
Under that URL (you can paste it to your browser to see) you can find a set of JWKs ([JSON Web Keys](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517)), basically a collection of public keys in a special format. In case of tokens issued by AAD you the JWKS_URI can be found on https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration.

JWT.io can read this information and find the key with the given `kid` and verify the token based on that.

This [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866513/how-to-validate-azure-ad-security-token) explains the verification of JWTs issued by AAD in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for this.
Almost exactly what I was looking for.