# Azure validating a JWT Token against the Azure B2C active directory

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, active-directory, azure-active-directory

A phone client sends me an access_token acquired from Active Directory B2C in Azure.
I have a server-side Spring Boot Application and want to check if the token's source is the Active Directory from Azure and was not manipulated by hand and it is valid.

I am expecting something like

```
        String validationUrl = "https://azure.microsoft/validate-token";
        // put token in header
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        String result = restTemplate.exchange(validationUrl, HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, String.class).getBody();
```

I tried implementation similar to :

```
        try {
            provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration"));
            jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
            algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
            algorithm.verify(jwt);// if the token signature is invalid, the method will throw SignatureVerificationException
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JwkException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SignatureVerificationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

**The result was always com.auth0.jwk.SigningKeyNotFoundException: No keys found in**

Then I tried another implementation :

```
  HttpsJwks httpsJkws = new HttpsJwks(url);
        HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver httpsJwksKeyResolver = new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJkws);
        JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setRequireExpirationTime() // the JWT must have an expiration time
                .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(3600) // allow some leeway in validating time based claims to account for clock skew
                .setVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJwksKeyResolver)
                .setRelaxVerificationKeyValidation()
                .build();

        try
        {
            //  Validate the JWT and process it to the Claims
            JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(accessToken);
            System.out.println("JWT validation succeeded! " + jwtClaims);
            return true;
        }
        catch (InvalidJwtException e)
        {
            // InvalidJwtException will be thrown, if the JWT failed processing or validation in anyway.
            // Hopefully with meaningful explanations(s) about what went wrong.
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT! " + e);
        }
```

The result was always **Invalid JWT! org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException: JWT processing failed. Additional details: [[17] Unable to process JOSE object (cause: org.jose4j.lang.UnresolvableKeyException: Unable to find a suitable verification key for JWS w/ header**

I have tried also following URLs:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/.well-known/openid-configuration

https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid=APP_ID

https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/discovery/v2.0/keys

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration

https://login.microsoftonline.com/discovery/v2.0/keys

Comment: Did you try to follow the steps done in the other language? Here is the same problem, widely explained for c# with code samples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870281/1595293

Answer (score 4):

The access_token of Azure AD is a JSON Web Token(JWT). So you could [validate JWT tokens using JWKS in Java](https://medium.com/trabe/validate-jwt-tokens-using-jwks-in-java-214f7014b5cf). `jwks_uri` can be acquired by the link that formed as `/.well-known/openid-configuration`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens).

[image]

```
DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
JwkProvider provider = provider = new UrlJwkProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys");
Jwk jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
algorithm.verify(jwt);
```

You could test your token online first, https://jwt.io/.

Comment: com.auth0.jwk.SigningKeyNotFoundException: Cannot obtain jwks from url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration/.well-known/jwks.json

Comment: @SorinPenteleiciuc Try to replace the url with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys`. `jwks_uri` is acquired by `/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: com.auth0.jwk.SigningKeyNotFoundException: Cannot obtain jwks from url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys.jwks_uri/.well-known/jwks.json

Comment: was there any luck on this. Facing same issue

Comment: new UrlJwkProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys"); for new UrlJwkProvider("https://l{{yout_tenant_name}}.b2clogin.com/{{your_tenant_name}}.onmicrosoft.com");  This is the URL you can find in you openId discover endpoint fo your tenant, and if this does not work you can also use this new UrlJwkProvider(new Url("{{your_jwks_uri }}")); this url can also be found in the discover endpoint. I recomend you the second option