# Logout the user from application if refresh token is revoked

Tags: java, azure, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

If refresh tokens issued to a user in OAuth2.0 are invalidated by the admin then I want the user to be logged out from application. Can anyone provide solution for this in Spring or Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring [session Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html) with [SessionRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html)

Then you can expire the session from anywhere using something like this

```
sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId).expireNow();
```

Comment: how can we get to know if the refresh token is invalidated by azure admin in AAD ? Is there any api call exposed for that validation ?

Comment: You can check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50893150/2015923 on how to validate the token